# Allow create-react-app to compile with ESLint errors

Tags: reactjs, compilation, create-react-app, eslint, prettier

I recently added ESLint and prettier with a bunch of configurations to create-react-app.

Here are the packages:

```
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
"prettier": "^2.1.2",
```

Now, the problem is that the development server fails to compile, because there are loads of ESLint errors in the project. It says:

```
Failed to compile

*list of errors*

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

This is highly intrusive. I need it to still be able to compile as I don't see a reason for it to refuse to do so because or some styling issues.

How can I prevent this from happening without doing some hack like setting all ESLint errors to warning level. I also do not want to eject.

I also wish not to put everything into `.eslintigore` during development as this would be very annoying for my team to have to change that file over and over during development.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you better look at  your build steps and enable eslint to compile with errors, we can't guess your build steps without code

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This is just create-react-app. All that should be out of the box, right? I have not ejected, so there shouldn't be anything custom going on here or am I missing something?

Comment: For some additional info: package.json has "build": "react-scripts build" and we are using "react-scripts": "4.0.0".

Comment: Providing the list of errors, or if as you mentioned, it's a nearly out of the box create react app the github repo/codesandbox fork of it would help people resolve your issue.

Comment: The repository is confidential. The specific errors are not relevant as they are just ESLint errors. As the question states - the development server crashes when there are any ESLint errors. I managed to figure out that the problem is indeed react-scripts version 4.0.0. Other people are having the same issue. Rolling back to the pervious version resolved the issue. I cannot think of any reason why they decided to make it act like this or if it is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly the same problem after using a Vite for a while and then returning to CRA and installing my usual Airbnb linting tools. I found [THIS](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10021#issuecomment-859813945)  solution on Github which basically says to add these lines to your package.json starting scripts

```
"start": "ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS='true'  react-scripts start",  
"build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN='true' react-scripts build",
```

This did the trick for me. It kept the linting errors showing in the code but unless they were breaking the code it compiled and ran no problem.

I don't think this is a long term solution, but it will do for a workaround...